# What is the Debian equivalent of `dnf --installroot`

Tags: debian, apt, debootstrap

`dnf` allows you to install in a different root than `/` by provding `--installroot`. This is frequently use with tools like [`buildah`](https://appfleet.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-buildah/). Is there any method to set the root location with `apt`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One method is to use [`debootstrap`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/debootstrap) with the `--include`,

> `--include=alpha,beta` Comma separated list of packages which will be added to download and extract lists.